# VS 2013 crashes while debugging Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, vs-unit-testing-framework

My VS 2013 is crashing when I am debugging VS tests, I get following details in the crash window. I have already repaired my VS 2013 once this morning and it was working fine for few hours.

***Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 12.0.40629.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5590c8a4
  Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ViewManager
  Problem Signature 05: 12.0.31101.0
  Problem Signature 06: 545487c9
  Problem Signature 07: 501
  Problem Signature 08: 2f
  Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentOutOfRange
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: bb02
  Additional Information 4: bb02c3b29c3f075104f1d0629e885cfc***

And in windows event viewer I get following

***The description for Event ID 0 from source Application cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
The following information was included with the event: 
Error Handler Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d). ---> System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d). ---> System.IO.PipeException: There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d).
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.OnAsyncReadComplete(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 numBytes)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.EndRead()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, Message& message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext) \r\n    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, Message& message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table***

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,

Salil

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend un-installing and re-installing Visual Studio.  It sounds like the install may be corrupted, and it has been my experience that Visual Studio is very temperamental if the install isn't done in a specific order.

The way I recommend doing it is to first un-install any service packs, working backwards if there are multiples (ex. remove SP4 before SP3), then when all SPs are removed, remove VS itself.

If you have multiple versions of VS installed, then do the same thing remove thenm (SPs first then VS) in REVERSE CHRONOLOGICAL ORDER, than re-install in CHRONOLOGICAL ORDER

For example, if you have VS 2010 & SP1, VS 2012, & VS 2013 & SP2, then un-install in the following order:

1. Remove VS2013 SP2
2. Remove VS2013
3. Remove VS 2012
4. Remove VS 2010 SP 1
5. Remove VS 2010

Then install in this order:

1. Install VS 2010
2. Install VS 2010 SP(latest)
3. Install VS 2012
4. Install VS 2012 SP(latest)
5. Install VS 2013
6. Install VS 2013(latest)

Comment: Thanks @Taegost, I re-installed the VS 2013. My crash issues continued after reinstall. But my issues are now resolved, but not because of re-install. I had some bad async await code in my unit tests and that crashed my entire environment. When I backed out the code and re-wrote it, it stopped crashing. Who knew async await would crash the entire environment.

Comment: @bhole Wow, that's weird.  I've seen bad exceptions cause the debugger to go haywire and skip breaks, but that's new to me.  Glad you found it!